# Criar um ficheiro em c no linux

Tags: c, linux

Tenho um trabalho da faculdade, que me é pedido para implementar um programa em “C” que produza ficheiros contendo números inteiros aleatórios do tipo `long` `int`, onde os números aleatórios devem estar entre 0 e `RAND_MAX`. 
Devem fazer ficheiros com o seguinte número de inteiros aleatorios por exemplo : 50000.
Este programa deve ter um parâmetro de entrada que é o numero de inteiros a produzir.
Como nao sei por onde começar, comecei a fazer o seguinte codigo :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("50000.c", "wb");
argv[50000];
fclose(fp);

}
```

Alguem me pode dar algumas dicas ? 
Este codigo é para ser feito depois no terminal do linux.

Comment: *Alguem me pode dar algumas dicas ?* **Liga os warnings do teu compilador e presta-lhes atencao.**

Comment: O problema é que eu nao sei qual compilador usar no linux podia-me dar o exemplo de algum ? Mas estou na direçao certa ?

Comment: Em principio todos os Linux tem instalado o gcc. Experimenta `gcc --help` para verificar.

Comment: ahahah eu conheço este trabalho :)

Answer (score -2):

ola amigo para rodar no linux usando o gcc basta usar a biblioteca stdio.h e mais nada.

Fiz um código onde RAND_MAX pode ser alterado no define e pronto, e pelo jeito ja sabe usar o FILE.

Espero ter ajudado !!

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define RAND_MAX 100

    int main()
    {
        long numAleatorio;
        int i, vezes;

        numAleatorio = 0;
        i = 0;
        vezes = 0;

        printf("\nEntre quantos numeros aleatorios voce quer: ");
        scanf("%d", &vezes);

        while(i <= vezes)
        {
          numAleatorio = rand()%RAND_MAX;
          printf("\n%d", numAleatorio);
          i++;
        };

        printf("\n");

        return 0;
    }
```

Para compilar tu faz:

```
gcc teuCodigo.c -o nomeQualquerSemPontoC
./nomeQualquerSemPontoC
```

Exemplo no me caso:

```
gcc test.c -o test
./test
```

Voila

Comment: A redefinição de `RAND_MAX` é ilegal! Ver [Standard 6.10.3p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3).

Comment: Vê os comentários na resposta do Lacobus. O teu ciclo `while(i <= vezes)` corre uma vez mais do que necessário.

Comment: tranquilo só alterar o  while(i <= vezes - 1) então

Comment: Usei RAND_MAX como constante não como palavra reservada. Caso queira usar o default  no método Rand o seja seu maximo não précisa do % na chamada de rand. Seria `numAleatorio = rand();`